# Node.js: make module use local `window` variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have such a function with imported module that I cannot edit

```js
function create() {
  const window = {}; // Normally initialized by JSDOM to make fake window
  const appboy = require("@braze/web-sdk");
}
```

What I want is that `appboy` sees the local `window` from `create` function.

I want to avoid `globalThis.window` because of race conditions of `create` function when run concurrently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, unless `@braze/web-sdk` explicitly provides a way to do it. The variables available to code are determined by what's in scope where that code is *defined*, not where it's used from. Unless that module provides some way to pass it a value for this (which I'm guessing it doesn't from the question), the only way to affect what it sees as `window` is to create/overwrite a global, as that's the only scope your code and the module have in common.

Depending on the constraints you're working under, one option might be to fork the module, add the necessary feature, and use that forked module in your code (perhaps even offering the original a pull request with the changes).

Comment: Thanks a lot.Unfortunately we can't make a fork as the package is closed-source and minified.

Comment: @pfoof - That (being closed source and minified) definitely raises the bar a bit, though it's not insurmountable with de-obfuscators and such. Whether it's worth the time investment is another story. :-)

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comment above, there exists a workaround where we can specify our own custom global context.
Node has native [VM](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) module that can sandbox scripts.
These sandboxed scripts can have it's own [context](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vmcreatecontextcontextobject-options).

Here is an example how it works to point us to the right way.
Say we have a little script

```js
console.log(window)
```

Depending on environment it can either print out global `Window` object if we run it in browser or throw a `RefferenceError` in Node.JS.

With a help of `vm.createContext` we can create our own `window` and specify it to the script.

```js
const vm = require('node:vm');  

// plain object for our purposes
const customGlobal = {
  window: 'Fake window',
  console //console should be passed to let our script option to use it
};  

// plain string with valid js script
const code = 'console.log(window)';  

// here we wrap code into executable environment
const script = new vm.Script(code);

// creating context from our plain object
const context = vm.createContext(customGlobal);
```

Now all we need to attach our context to script and run it

```js
script.runInContext(context);
```

The result of execution will be a `Fake window` text in our console.

As a result of this quick example now we know that we can apply similar approach to the external node_modules.

I want to believe that this one will guide you to solution of the problem.

Comment: A couple of issues there: 1. The starting point isn't code in a string, though, it's a `require`'d module (which may in turn `require` other modules, etc.). 2. The module may well be using any of [many other globals](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/globals.html) (`process`, `fetch`, `Buffer`, `Blob`) -- how will you ensure it has what it needs (even in edge cases)? Can you show how you'd handle that (in particular the first issue)? That's the crux of the whether this is a viable solution or not.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder we can re-implement our own `require` with custom context. `require` in general is a combination of reading file and it's execution. First part could be done with a help of `node:fs` and the second one with `node:vm` like I showed here

Comment: @T.J.Crowder second question could be solved with passing "enough" parameters into our `customGlobal`. Same way as we passed `console` to allow our sandbox to use it, we can pass `process`, `fetch` etc

Comment: @T.J.Crowder here is implementation [example](https://github.com/HowProgrammingWorks/Sandboxes/blob/master/JavaScript/framework.js) in how.programming.works [repo](https://github.com/HowProgrammingWorks/Sandboxes/tree/master/JavaScript)

Comment: Ah, yes, a facade on the real `require` (since that's a global). Would be much more difficult with ESM. Fair enough.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder very true. ESM was such a pain when we attempted to rewrite our custom loader.